# Java MySQL Authentication System

Tags: java, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create my own authentication system that connects from a Java program to MySQL database or to a PHP page that accesses the MySQL page. The Java program would check to see if the user is in the database and if it is, it would determine the list of features to display. I am currently trying to work on something simple, then work my way up.

I have searched on Google, but there are quite a few things out there; I wasn't sure which was the best way to go about doing this and what technologies to use from what I saw. I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on how I should go about doing this or if they had an document, article, blog, etc that I could use to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache Shiro, its well documented and you can configure it with mysql(jdbc) database http://shiro.apache.org/